# Selenium - To compare and verify image in PDF file with front end

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a requirement to compare the images in the PDF file to the font end of the web application. I am using the Selenium Web Driver and I have tried to compare with PDFBox but it won't read the images. Is there any way to achieve this? please suggest

Comment: Please delete your comment and put the key information into a new answer. Old comments are periodically deleted, where answers are not.

Comment: Can you clarify the requirement? Do you need to test that the data in the PDF is the same as the website?
Is this some sort of form?
Do you have access to the code which is generating the PDF?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can not do this out of the box, but you can combine it with [Sikuli](http://sikulix.com). Or you use a web testing software with built-in [PDF testing](https://a9t9.com/kantu/scraping#ocr) support.

Answer (score 0):

With Selenium, you can [take a screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver).

You can try to create a PDF file with the same structure as you the one you have, and [compare both](https://github.com/vslavik/diff-pdf).